# Conflict between sidebar and tables with many columns

Tags: navigation, tables, menu, sidebar, information-density

I am designing an internal tool for a client. This tool is very information dense and most of its content is tables with a lot of columns.

When designing the navigation I had thought of a sidebar, but as it takes up part of the horizontal space it generates horizontal scroll in many of the tables.

I have thought of 3 solutions:

- Change to top navigation
- Collapse sidebar (but I'm worried about relying only on icons to communicate the sections)
- Try to reduce the information in the tables (I've tried but my client doesn't want to hear about it).

What do you think should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse the sidebar and not rely only on icons but also on tooltips that show up while hovering on the icon.

Comment: Yes, you can also have an hamburger menù at the top of the sidebar to collapse/expand the entire bar

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-level top navigation:

[image]

I don't know what your navigation looks like now, so this is the best I can do.

Honestly, a single level can do as well, you just lose a lot of the benefits of using a side nav. Maybe reducing the font size? But again, I can't say much since I don't know what your nav looks like at the moment